# Mathematica integrates centered functions, but can not integrate shifted ones

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Mathematica seems to integrate this function:
$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} d w\, \frac{\sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} wt \right)}{w^2}
\frac{\frac{\gamma ^2}{4}}{ \left(w^2+\frac{\gamma ^2}{4}\right)}$,
which is Lorentzian product with Sinc squared.

But it can not integrate shifted version shifted by a constant value $a>0$:
$\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} d w\, \frac{\sin ^2\left(\frac{1}{2}  (a-w)t\right)}{(a-w)^2}
\frac{\frac{\gamma ^2}{4}}{ \left((w-a)^2+\frac{\gamma ^2}{4}\right)}$

Why would be that? Does not seem that integration would be different for shifted function. $\gamma$ and $t$ are variating parameters, width of Lorentzian peak and time, respectively.

Here is my code, I also use assumptions for integration to be easier:

```
Lorentz = (1/4) \[Gamma]^2/((w - a)^2 + (\[Gamma]^2/4));
Sincfunction = Sin[(1/2 (a - w)*t)]^2/(a - w)^2;

IIntegral2 = 
 Integrate[Lorentz*Sincfunction, {w, - Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {Im[\[Gamma]] == 0, Re[\[Gamma]] > 0, Im[t] == 0, 
    Re[t] >= 0, Im[a] == 0, Re[a] >= 0  , 1/2*Re[\[Gamma]] < Re[a], 
    Im[w] == 0 }]
```

Then to simplify I usually expand it into series

```
Series[IIntegral2, {t, Infinity, 2}, {\[Gamma], Infinity, 1}] // Normal
Series[IIntegral2, {t, 0, 2}, {\[Gamma], 0, 2}] // Normal
```

So when I set $a=0$, everything works fine, bet when $a>0$, then Mathematica gets stuck.

Comment: Internal code is probably not seeing the right change of variable.

Comment: Would there be a way to correct it or it is up to software developers?

Comment: A little of both, perhaps. It never hurts to express a problem in the simplest (for the software) form possible. It's also possible the software will improve in future to automate this.

Comment: In the meantime, it wouldn't hurt to [report this to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback) (and perhaps link to this thread), so it gets on record.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica is able to integrate both cases, but for the shifted function **100 times longer** calculation is needed.

```
Clear[Lorentz,Sincfunction]
Lorentz[a_,γ_,w_]:=(1/4) γ^2/((w-a)^2+(γ^2/4));
Sincfunction[a_,t_,w_]=Sin[(1/2 (a-w)*t)]^2/(a-w)^2;
```

Compare the times

```
Integrate[Lorentz[a,γ,w] Sincfunction[a,t,w],{w,-Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions->t>0&&γ>0&&a∈Reals]//Timing
Out[2]= {99.977,(π (-2+2 E^(-((t γ)/2))+t γ))/(2 γ)}
```

and

```
Integrate[Lorentz[0,γ,w] Sincfunction[0,t,w],{w,-Infinity,Infinity},Assumptions->t>0&&γ>0]//Timing
Out[3]= {1.00345,(π (-2+2 E^(-((t γ)/2))+t γ))/(2 γ)}
```

The results are identical. In order to understand the large time-difference compare  the respective indefinite integrations:

```
Integrate[Lorentz[a,γ,w] Sincfunction[a,t,w],w,Assumptions->t>0&&γ>0&&a∈Reals];//Timing
Integrate[Lorentz[0,γ,w] Sincfunction[0,t,w],w,Assumptions->t>0&&γ>0];//Timing
Out[4]= {0.691755,Null}
Out[5]= {0.128017,Null}
```

Thus, most of the time is spent to establish that antiderivatives are continuous functions and taking the limits according to the fundamental theorem of calculus.